# Should I use plural or singular fore 'more than one' and why?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was writing the sentence and understood I do not know whether to use plural or singular:

*If more than one attribute **was / were** found ...*

Comment: Related: [Which is correct: “one or more is” or “one or more are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13284/which-is-correct-one-or-more-is-or-one-or-more-are) and [“There is/are more than one”. What's the difference?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/there-is-are-more-than-one-whats-the-difference)

Comment: Gives me another chance to name-drop: 'Don't take any notice of teachers and textbooks in such matters. Nor of logic. It is good to say "more than one passenger _was_ hurt," although more than one equals at least two and therefore logically the verb ought to be plural _were_ not singular _was_!' [C S Lewis; italics mine]