# Non-standard sentence construction with "there is no"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, negation, parallelism, there-is

I have just come across this very unusual construction, in my view at least. Is it correct and if yes, what grammar rules apply here? I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this and refer me to proper English grammar and usage references on this. Thanks a lot in advance!

"The main conclusion of this study was that **there is no one, or five, or even ten such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector**."

Comment: The "no one" IS confusing. There must be a way around it! Perhaps, "The main conclusion of this study was that there is no single failure (or failures--say, five or even ten) which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector."

Comment: I assume you're fazed by either **no one, or five, or even ten such failures** or by **once removed**. They both seem perfectly ordinary usages to me (except the first **or** is redundant and a bit ungainly). Which one bothers you, and why?

Comment: Dear rhetorician, thanks a lot for your quick reply! I also think it should be possible to rephrase this bit somehow. But not sure how exactly. I have always thought of myself as quite good at English until I faced this sentence. Do you think, "it is not just one, five or even ten..." could solve the problem?

Comment: Dear FumbleFingers, thanks a lot for your prompt response. Indeed, I am surprised by the use of "there is no one, or five, or even ten such failures". I am not a native speaker. But this bit has rendered worthless many years of my editorial and journalistic experience. I understand what the writer here wants to say, but think there must be better ways of doing that. Not quite sure though how.

Comment: It's not quite 100% grammatical, because the disjoined subjects disagree in number, and you can't tell whether the verb should be *is* or *are*.  But there's no easy way to fix it, either.  It's reasonable to ignore the little agreement problem.

Comment: @Greg: Per [this answer to an earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/13369/2637), I don't think there's anything "ungrammatical" about such usages. In OP's specific case I'd expect all competent writers to be happy with the plural verb form. Firstly because it's describing a "general case", and secondly because in such "mixed plurality" contexts we normally agree with the *last* element in the list of potential "subjects".

Comment: I would write the sentence like this: **There are neither one, nor five, nor even ten such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector.**

Comment: It is a very curious way of presenting a 'finding'.  I'm still not clear what it is trying to say.  Is it that *even if all the failures are removed the development of the sub-sector would not be boosted ?*  There must be a more straight-forward way of expressing the point.

Comment: I have two problems with "there is no one, or five, or even ten such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector". First, correct me if I am wrong, logically and gramatically, when we say "there is NO...", we mean it does not exist. I cannot think of any instance when it could mean it exists but the number is higher etc. Second, I cannot comprehend how failures could boost anything. Their removal could, but not they in themselves as it currently follows from the extract "such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector".

Comment: "The main conclusion of this study was that there is no set of one, five, or even ten such failures whose removal would [don't understand the rest]"

Comment: Note that the clause would be unambiguous and would cause no confusion if spoken, because the nonconstituent string "no one" would be stressed and intoned quite differently from the construction _no one_.

Comment: "one, or five, or ten" is a simple list (not a use of a parenthetical phrase).  Nothing weird about it (though the non-native English speaker may get confused by treating "no one" as a pair, rather than applying "no" to the entire clause).  Using "or" between all options (along with the commas) is a rhetorical device and I find it to be "legal" and effective.

Comment: @JohnLawler - If one actually pays attention to the commas when reading then the pause after "one" produces much the same effect.  And the regular appearance of ", or" between the elements of the list further removes ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sentence that the poster asks about:

> The main conclusion of this study was that there is no one, or five, or even ten such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector.

As nearly as I can tell, the intended meaning of that sentence is essentially this:

> The main conclusion of this study was that removing one, five, or even ten such failures would not boost development of the sub-sector.

Grammatically there is nothing wrong with using "no one" instead of "not one" in th original wording, although that choice does invite readers to take the wrong path and imagine initially that "no one" is being used as a synonym for "nobody." Likewise there is nothing grammatically wrong with including the "or" before "five," although it tends to prolong the time that readers who took the wrong turn at "no one" will remain on the wrong path before figuring out their mistake.

I do, however, see a logical problem with the wording, "there [are] no ... such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector." That wording amounts to saying that no removed failure would boost development of the sub-sector. But in my opinion, looking at the effect of "a failure, once removed," isn't the same as looking at the effect of "the removal of a failure." After all, you wouldn't say, "once removed, those failures boosted development of the sub-sector."

Ultimately, the crucial question to ask about the original sentence isn't whether the author's convoluted wording contains any grammatical errors. From a practical perspective, the issue is whether readers can make sense of what the author is saying without dedicating undue effort to the task—and judged by that standard, the original wording (especially in print) is very poor. My reworded version (in the second block of boxed text above) conveys the intended meaning in fewer words, without inviting misinterpretation or requiring readers to iron out the author's iffy logic.

Answer (score 0):

The usage is correct IMO. "There is no one such failure...". The parenthetic "five or even ten" just make the sentence flow awkwardly.

Comment: The fact that _failures_ is plural here disqualifies the classical parenthesis analysis.

Comment: I have two problems with "there is no one, or five, or even ten such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector". First, correct me if I am wrong, logically and gramatically, when we say "there is NO...", we mean it does not exist. I cannot think of any instance when it could mean it exists but the number is higher etc. Second, I cannot comprehend how failures could boost anything. Their removal could, but not they in themselves as it currently follows from the extract "such failures which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector".

Comment: It's a 3-item list, not a parenthetical clause.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'no' to 'not' and it will make more sense; or change 'is' to 'are'.

Comment: That would make a lot more sense, but I think the meaning would be subtly different.  "Not one failure" is not exactly the same as "No *one failure*."

Answer (score 0):

The sentence (aside from the ambiguous "s" on failures) is grammatically correct, but very confusing.  "No one" is a commonly used phrase that usually is the opposite of "everyone."  However, in this case what is meant is "there is no **one failure,**" where "one failure" is a unit, not "no one."  "One failure" is not as common a phrase, but what it indicates in this case is a single source of problems.  The general model is "one *X*" where *X* is something of unique importance (like Tolkien's "One Ring").

That, in itself, wouldn't confuse most people, but inserting "or five, or even ten such" in between "one" and "failure[s]" breaks apart the actual unit of meaning, and makes it appear as though the other meaning is (nonsensically) intended.  The intent was to build on the idea that there is no single source of the problem, and to extend it by saying there is no finite list of fixable problems.  This might have been too ambitious for a single sentence, however.  A better version might have been:

> ...there is no "one failure" which, once removed, would boost the development of the sub-sector.  There is not even any five, or ten such failures.

Apparently the sub-sector's development cannot be boosted... at least not by removing failures!